# Best and worst case time for Algorithm S when time complexity changes in accordance to n being even/odd

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

The following is a homework assignment, so I would rather get hints or bits of information that would help me figure this out, and not complete answers.

> Consider S an algorithm solution to a problem that takes as input an array A of size n. After analysis, the following conclusion was obtained:
>
> - Algorithm S executes an O(n)-time computation for each even number in A.
> - Algorithm S executes an O(logn)-time computation for each odd number in A.
>
> What are the best and worst case time for algorithm S?

From this I understand that the time complexity changes in accordance to n being even or odd. In other words, if n is even, S takes O(n) time and when n is odd, S takes O(logn).

Is it a simple matter of taking the best case and the worst case of both growth-rates, and choosing their boundaries? Meaning:

Best case of O(n) is O(1), and worst case is O(n).

Best case of O(logn) is O(logn) and worst case is O(logn).

Therefore the best case for Algorithm S is O(logn) and the worst case is O(n)?

Am I missing something? or am I wrong in assessing the different best/worst case of both cases of big-Oh?

---

**1st attempt**:

Ok, so I completely misunderstood the problem. Thanks to candu, I can now better understand what is required of me, and so try to calculate the best and worst case better.

It seems that Algorithm S changes its runtime according to *EACH number in A*. If the number is even, the runtime is O(n), and if the number is odd, we get O(logn).

The worst case will be composed of an array A of n even numbers, and for each the algorithm will run O(n). In other words, the worst case runtime for Algorithm S should be n*O(n).

The best case will be composed of an array A of n odd numbers, and for each the algorithm will run O(logn). The best case runtime for algorithm S should be n*O(logn).

Am I making any sense? is it true then that:

Best case of algorithm S is nO(logn) and worst case is nO(n)?

If that is true, can it be rewritten? for example, as O(log^n(n)) and O(n^n)? or is this an arithmetic mistake?

---

**2nd attempt**:

Following JuanLopes' response, it seems like I can rewrite nO(n) as O(n*n) or O(n^2), and nO(logn) as O(nlogn).

Does it make sense now that Algorithm S runs at O(nlogn) at the best case, and O(n^2) at the worst case?

Comment: Usually it's written O(n log n) and O(n^2). O(n^n) is another thing.

Comment: @JuanLopes So, if I get you right, when a certain runtime has a coefficient, such as in nO(n) or nO(logn), it is simply inserted into the parenthesis and becomes the inner function's coefficient? that is why nO(n) = O(n*n) = O(n^2) and nO(logn) = O(nlogn)?

Comment: Yes, unless the coefficient is a constant. kO(n) = O(n) if k is constant.

Comment: Which, in this case, is _not_ a constant, so I can safely claim what I claim!... yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion here: the algorithm runtime doesn't depend on `n` being even or odd, but on whether the numbers in `A` are even or odd.

With that in mind, what sort of input `A` would make Algorithm S run faster?  Slower?

Also: it doesn't make sense to say that the best case of `O(n)` is `O(1)`.  Suppose I have an algorithm ("Algorithm Q") that is `O(n)`; all I can say is that there exists a constant `c` such that, for any input of size `n`, Algorithm Q takes less than `cn` time.  There is *no guarantee that I can find specific inputs for which Algorithm Q is `O(1)`.*

To give a concrete example, this takes linear time *no matter what input it is passed*:

```
def length(A):
  len = 0
  for x in A:
    len += 1
  return len
```

Comment: Woha, I have not notice that very important detail about the content of the array. Also, I see what you mean with your example. So, it is pretty much impossible to state anything about a runtime's best/worst case depending solely on its order, because we don't really know anything about the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts.
First, there is no mention of asymptotically tight time. So an O(n) algorithm can actually be an O(logn) one. So just imagine the best case running time this algorithm can be in this case. I know, this is a little picky. But this is a homework, I guess it's always welcome to mention all the possibilities.

Second, even if it's asymptotically tight, it doesn't necessarily mean it's tight for all elements. Consider insertion sort. For each new element to insert, we need to find the correct position in the previous already-sorted subarray. The time is proportional to the number of element in subarray, which has the upper bound O(n). But it doesn't mean each new element need exactly #n comparisons to insert. Actually, the shorter the subarray, the quicker the insertion.

Back to this question. "executes an O(logn)-time computation for each odd number in A." Let's assume all odd nubmers. It could be that the first odd takes O(log1), the second odd takes O(log2), .. the nth takes O(logn). Totally, it takes O(logn!). It doesn't contradicts "O(logn) for each odd number".

As to worst case, you may analysize it in much the same way.

Comment: but isn't the running time of Algorithm S is the sum of all running times for each element? Shouldn't I consider that when trying to calculate the best and worst case, as I am trying to do in the second section of my question? I mean, in the best case, it _will_ take the algorithm n*O(logn) to run, because that's what "executes an O(logn)-time computation for **each** odd number in A" means...

Comment: You need to have a deeper understanding of big-O notation. O(logn) means a function has an **upper bound** of O(logn). A function that takes constant time (thus O(1)) belongs to O(logn) as well; It makes more sense when it goes down to the level of individual elements. Check the example of insertion sort above.

Comment: I am aware big-Oh gives an upper bound to a function. My problem with this is that I don't see how O(logn) is sufficient to describe the best case, when the algorithm is bound to run at least n times. O(n) does not belong in O(logn). Apologies if my lack of knowledge is irritating.

Comment: Btw, the asymptotically tight upper bound is denoted by the small o-notation instead. Chapter 3 ("Growth of Functions") of [Introduction to Algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) has an excellent discussion on this.

Comment: Also, can you please explain why the total run time is O(logn!) and not O(nlogn)? Isn't it supposed to be O(log1)+O(log2)+...+O(logn) and not O(log1)*O(log2)*...*O(logn)

Comment: Well, I didn't say it takes `O(logn)` for `S` to run in the best case. It's the upper bound for a **single** element, which has been stated by @candu. You need sum them up. What I'm trying to point out in this reply is that it's not necessarily as simple as `n*log(n)` (yes, equally `O(nlogn)`, you asked). Actually you can get a much smaller number.

Comment: `log1 + log2 +.. + logn = log(1*2*.. *n) = log(n!)`. math..math.

Comment: Oh, yes. you're right. Sorry and thank you. Ok, this makes much more sense to me. So, now to your point. It might not be as simple as O(nlogn), but isn't that the case for when array A is composed of n odd numbers? which is the best case for Algorithm S?

Comment: It can, but not necessarily. `O(logn!)` **IS** applying to the case of n odd numbers, and `O(logn!) < O(nlogn) = O(log(n^n))`, you know that right?

Comment: now I do! thanks for everything. Sorry for not taking notice for the first part of your response. This topic is confusing me enough as it is. I am trying no to over-complicate it with things that were not asked of me.